# I can't get reviews of each product page in Aliexpress

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap data from this website: https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20220313071939&SearchText=bluetooth+earphones Especially I want to get all reviews from each product page. The main issue is that I'm struggling to get this surrounded bottom in order to scrape each comment and customer country:
Here is a photo showing that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGnos.png)

This is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from lxml import html 
import cssselect
from time import sleep
from itertools import zip_longest
import csv

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r"C:/Users/OUISSAL/Desktop/wscraping/XEW/scraping/codes/msedgedriver")
url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?trafficChannel=main&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=bluetooth+earphones&ltype=wholesale&SortType=default&page={}'
    
with open ("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    wr.writerow(["Title","Price", "Currency", "Reviews", "Number of orders", "Shipping Cost", "Product links", "Country","Comments"])
    for page_nb in range(1, 4):
        print('---', page_nb, '---')
        driver.get(url.format(page_nb))
        sleep(2)
        current_offset = 0
        while True:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
            sleep(.5)  
            new_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
            print(new_offset,current_offset)
            if new_offset <= current_offset:
                break
            current_offset = new_offset
        sleep(3)
        tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
        results = []
        for product in tree.xpath('//div[@class="JIIxO"]//a'):
            title = product.xpath('.//h1/text()')
            if title:
                title = title[0]
                price = product.cssselect('div.mGXnE._37W_B span')
                price = [x.text for x in price]
                currency = price[0]
                price = ''.join(price[1:])
                review = product.xpath('.//span[@class="eXPaM"]/text()')
                if review:
                    review = review[0]
                else:
                    review = ''
                nb_sold = product.xpath('.//span[@class="_1kNf9"]/text()')
                if nb_sold:
                    nb_sold = nb_sold[0]
                else:
                    nb_sold = ''
                ship_cost = product.xpath('.//span[@class="_2jcMA"]/text()')
                if ship_cost:
                    ship_cost = ship_cost[0]
                else:
                    ship_cost = ''
                    
###########################################                
                links = product.xpath('//div[@class="JIIxO"]//a/@href')
                if links:
                    links = links[0]
                else:
                    links = ''
                    
# scraping data from each inner page     
                    
                for link in links :
                    driver.get(link)
                    sleep(2)
                    current_offset = 0
                    while True:
                        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
                        sleep(.5) 
                        new_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
                        print(new_offset,current_offset)
                        if new_offset <= current_offset:
                            break
                        current_offset = new_offset 
        
                    sleep(3)
                    tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
                    for cmt in tree.xpath('//*[@id="transction-feedback"]/div[5]/div[1]'):
                        country = cmt.xpath('.//div[@class="user-country"]//b/text()')
                        if country:
                            country = country[0]
                        else:
                            country = ''
                            
                        comment = cmt.xpath('.//span[@id="0.0.0.i4.5dc4sSFDsSFD5B"]/text()')
                        if comment:
                            comment = comment[0]
                        else:
                            comment = ''
                
                row = [title, price, currency, review, nb_sold, ship_cost, links,country, comment]
                results.append(row)
                
        print('len(results):', len(results))
        wr.writerows(results)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Can you get us a sample url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: This is the url that I want to scrape :   https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20220309030820&SearchText=bluetooth+earphones

Comment: do you get error when you run it ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you display window to see if it scroll and add items? Some pages may add new items but also remove items which you don't see - and this need to use loop which scroll partially and get new items, etc. Do you try to use `print()` to see what you have in variables?

Comment: now I see your mistake. You use `lxml` to get data - but you scroll AFTER getting `html.fromstring()` - so you scroll in wrong moment. You have to scroll before `html.fromstring()`, or you should use selenium functions to get values - it also can use `xpath` (so you don't need `lxml`)

Comment: I have no idea why you search `product_tree` if later you use `absolute` xpath to get other elements. `product_tree` can be usefull if you would use `relative` xpath with `.` (dot) at the beginning  to search values only for single product.

Comment: there is other problem: after scrolling it change HTML structure and using all `/div/` is useless. You should use `class`. `id` and other `attributes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

**First:**

You have to use `html.fromstring(driver.page_source)` **AFTER** you scroll down.

**Second:**

It adds items only when they are displayed inside window (in `viewport`) so you can't jump directly to the end of page. You have to scroll partially (in loop) using i.e. `window.innerHeight`.

```py
current_offset = 0

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
    sleep(.5)  # JavaScript has time to add elements

    new_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
    #print(new_offset,current_offset)
    if new_offset <= current_offset:
        break

    current_offset = new_offset
```

---

Full working code with other changes in `xpath`.

It gives me 60 items on every page.

```py
from selenium import webdriver  
from lxml import html 
from time import sleep
from itertools import zip_longest
import csv

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r"C:/Users/OUISSAL/Desktop/wscraping/XEW/scraping/codes/msedgedriver")
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?trafficChannel=main&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=bluetooth+earphones&ltype=wholesale&SortType=default&page={}'
    
with open ("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:

    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    wr.writerow(["Title","Price", "Currency", "Reviews", "Number of orders"])

    for page_nb in range(1, 4):
        print('---', page_nb, '---')
        
        driver.get(url.format(page_nb))
        sleep(2)

        # jump to the end of page        
        #driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')

        # scroll partially
        current_offset = 0
        while True:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
            sleep(.5)  # JavaScript has time to add elements
            new_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
            print(new_offset,current_offset)
            if new_offset <= current_offset:
                break
            current_offset = new_offset
        
        sleep(3)
        
        tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
        
        results = []
        
        for product in tree.xpath('//div[@class="JIIxO"]//a'):
            title = product.xpath('.//h1/text()')
            #print('[DEBUG] title:', title)
            
            if title:
                title = title[0]
                #print('[DEBUG] title:', title)
                
                price = product.cssselect('div.mGXnE._37W_B span')
                price = [x.text for x in price]

                # for `$ 35.00`
                currency = price[0]
                price = ''.join(price[1:])
                
                # for `35.00 zł`
                #currency = price[-1]
                #price = ''.join(price[:-1])
                
                #print('[DEBUG] price:', price)
                #print('[DEBUG] currency:', currency)

                review = product.xpath('.//span[@class="eXPaM"]/text()')
                if review:
                    review = review[0]
                else:
                    review = ''
                #print('[DEBUG] review:', review)
                    
                nb_sold = product.xpath('.//span[@class="_1kNf9"]/text()')
                if nb_sold:
                    nb_sold = nb_sold[0]
                else:
                    nb_sold = ''
                #print('[DEBUG] nb_sold:', nb_sold)
                    
                row = [title, price, currency, review, nb_sold]
                results.append(row)
                #print('[DEBUG] row:', row)
            
        print('len(results):', len(results))
        wr.writerows(results)  

driver.close()
```

Comment: Pleaaaase help!!!

Comment: @OuissalBELAOUNI if you have new problem then create new question on new page.

Comment: Sorry but I coudn't